# iOS Simulator significant change location service accuracy

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, geofencing

I'm implementing geofencing to go into an app.

It turns out, that Wifi being enabled is extremely important to accuracy. If I switch it off on my iPhone I will get several region entry events simultaneously even though my test locations are all over the city.
It works fine with Wifi.

When using the iOS Simulator I cannot get the desired accuracy at all. It behaves like it does on the phone with wifi off. The weird thing is, it used to work. I used the built in 'City bicycle ride' with some regions on the route a couple of times. Then it stopped working. When I try that now it will send entry events for every region I put on the route.
This makes testing my geofencing on the simulator impossible which is a problem. Btw it has wifi on.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I tried deleting an reinstalling the app on the simulator and resetting it. No luck.

Comment: The simulator takes the internet connection of the pc and thus uses the precision it can get from your pc actually. So.. what kind of internet connection do you have? is it a 3g? even if your pc is connected to a wireless network, the router may be connected to a 3g modem.

Comment: @Fawkes, would I then be able to use my phone's 4g connection (internet sharing) and expect better accuracy? It's just weird that it used to work just fine. Maybe I should try different connection sources.

Comment: I am not sure, try it, but I guess you'll have the same precision as if your phone with 4g enabled and wifi disabled.

Comment: Sadly yes. I wonder what the variable is here. It used to work perfectly on the simulator when I first began working on it.

Comment: I would think the internet source was different.. Maybe it was a fiber or something fixed rather than cellular data.